# java parsing json fro distancematrix google api

Tags: java, json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to read the `distance` and `duration` fields of this JSON response

```
 {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "342 E 110th St, New York, NY 10029, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "303 E 43rd St, New York, NY 10017, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.9 km",
                  "value" : 6853
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 926
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Here is my code

```
try {           
   InputStream is = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=40.750404,-73.971489&destinations=40.79248,-73.938805").openStream();      
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   json = readAll(rd);
} catch(Exception e) {
}
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) obj;

JSONArray jsonObject1 = (JSONArray) jb.get("rows");
JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get(0);
JSONArray jsonObject3 = (JSONArray)jsonObject2.get("elements");
JSONObject distanceObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject3.get(0);
JSONArray distanceArr = (JSONArray)distanceObj.get("distance");

double distance_text= (double) distanceArr.get(0); 
System.out.println( "distance = "+distance_text);
```

But the code results in:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

How can I fix it ? Is there simpler method than this?
Thanks

Comment: `distanceObj.get("distance")` returns `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `distance` is not an array.

```
JSONArray jsonObject1 = (JSONArray) jb.get("rows");
JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get(0);
JSONArray jsonObject3 = (JSONArray)jsonObject2.get("elements");
JSONObject elementObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject3.get(0);
JSONObject distanceObj = (JSONObject)elementObj.get("distance");
String distance = distanceObj.getString("text");
```

If you want the double you will need to remove the `km` part of the string and then parse it.

For example:

```
distance = distance.replace(" km", "").trim();
double value = Double.parseDouble(distance);
```